# Usage of Fastify JWT with postgraphile

Tags: graphql, fastify, postgraphile

I am trying to setup postgraphile with fastify server and it worked as expected. Now I added authentication middleware using a fastify-jwt plugin to graphql endpoint exposed by postgraphile but when I access the graphql endpoint using graphql IDE I was able to see the scheme and able to query the data without Authorization Header. How can I make the fastify-jwt plugin to work with postgraphile?

Here is my code:

installPostgraphile.js

```
const { postgraphile } = require('postgraphile');
const PgSimplifyInflectorPlugin = require('@graphile-contrib/pg-simplify-inflector');

module.exports = async function (fastify) {
  fastify.log.info('Establishing PostgreSQL DB connection...');

  await fastify
    .use(
      postgraphile(
        'postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/demo',
        'app_public',
        {
          dynamicJson: true,
          appendPlugins: [PgSimplifyInflectorPlugin],
          enhanceGraphiql: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? true : false,
          graphileBuildOptions: {
            nestedMutationsSimpleFieldNames: true,
            nestedMutationsDeleteOthers: false,
          },
          disableQueryLog: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? true : false,
          graphiql: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? true : false,
          watchPg: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? true : false,
        }
      )
    )
    .ready((err) => {
      if (err) return fastify.log.error(err);
    });
};
```

server.js

```
const Fastify = require('fastify');
const helmet = require('fastify-helmet');
const cors = require('fastify-cors');
const JWT = require('fastify-jwt');
const fp = require('fastify-plugin');
const installPostgraphile = require('./installPostgraphile');

const app = Fastify({
  logger: true,
});

// Register Plugins
app.register(cors);
app.register(helmet);

app.register(JWT, {
  secret: 'supersecret',
});

app.post('/login', (req, reply) => {
  // some code to authenticate
  const token = instance.jwt.sign({ payload: { user: 'foo' } });
  reply.send(token);
});

app.decorate('authenticate', async function (request, reply) {
  try {
    // Autorization logic
    await request.jwtVerify();
  } catch (err) {
    reply.send(err);
  }
});

app.addHook('onRoute', (routeOptions) => {
  if (routeOptions.url === '/graphql') {
    routeOptions.preValidation = [app.authenticate];
  }
});

app.register(fp(installPostgraphile));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    app.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem: you are using the fastify middleware function [`fastify.use(postgraphile..`](https://www.fastify.io/docs/v2.13.x/Middleware/).

The functions registered as middleware are executed before the `preValidation` hook, where you added the `app.authenticate` logic.
The [lifecycle doc](https://www.fastify.io/docs/v2.13.x/Lifecycle/) shows that: as you can see the only hook that runs before the middleware is `onRequest`, so you should change:

```
routeOptions.onRequest = [app.authenticate];
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing the code as you said. But still, I see the same issue.

```app.addHook('onRoute', (routeOptions) => {
  if (routeOptions.url === '/graphql') {
    routeOptions.onRequest = [app.authenticate];
  }```

Comment: Could you add the log of `routeOptions`?